# ROS Answers SE migration: Web interface

Tags: ros, web, roslibjs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, i'm new in this field and i'm planing to make a test in a turtlebot, the idea is basically to control the robot via web. I read some examples using roslibjs but i don't know how difficult is it.

For the first example: Controling the movement of the robot via internet.

For the second example: Reading information with the kinect via internet (i.e. streaming the camera)

It is not related to AI, but i want to know if there are some APIs to have success on both examples.

1)How difficult it is?

2)Which steps did you suggest me to start?

3)Which libraries exist for this?

Thanks beforehand

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199654/web-interface/) by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on ROS Answers with karma: 82 on 2014-12-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suppose you can do it easily using roslibjs as you mentioned.

Look into publishing and subscribing data in  [roslibjs basic Tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/roslibjs/Tutorials/BasicRosFunctionality)

> For the first example: Controling the
> movement of the robot via internet.

Publishing control commands i.e cmd_vel (geometry_msgs/Twist) incase of turtlebot

> For the second example: Reading  information with the kinect via  internet (i.e. streaming the camera)

Subscribe to image data.  [web_video_server](http://wiki.ros.org/web_video_server) provides this functionality.

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on 2014-12-17**:
i can mix this functions in the webpage of the robot with also 3d mapping? (or the camera ok kinect only does one thing per time?)

There is an starter tutorial that i can see to get my first touch with the robot? (without broking it)

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-12-17**:
yes , its visualizing of data. For 3d data , do you mean you want to do 3d mapping on server side with data from robot ? i guess no library is available for that.

**Comment by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) on 2014-12-17**:
You can visualize 3D data with ros3djs (https://github.com/RobotWebTools/ros3djs)